# Nhibernate ValueType Collection as delimited string in DB

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a legacy db that I am mapping with Nhibernate.
And in several locations a list och strigs or domain objects are mapped as a delimited string in the database. Either 'string|string|string' in the value type cases and like 'domainID|domainID|domainID' in the references type cases.

I know I can create a dummy property on the class and map to that fields but I would like to do it in a more clean way, like when mapping Enums as their string representation with the [EnumStringType](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2006/03/14/140949.aspx) class.

Is a IUserType the way to go here?

Thanks in advance
/Johan

Answer (score 5):

I am using this:

```
public class DelimitedList : IUserType
{
    private const string delimiter = "|";

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return object.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var r = rs[names[0]];
        return r == DBNull.Value 
            ? new List<string>()
            : ((string)r).SplitAndTrim(new [] { delimiter });
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        object paramVal = DBNull.Value;
        if (value != null)
        {
            paramVal = ((IEnumerable<string>)value).Join(delimiter);
        }
        var parameter = (IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];
        parameter.Value = paramVal;
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new SqlType[] { new StringSqlType() }; }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(IList<string>); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

SplitAndTrim is my own extension of string.  Then in the class (using ActiveRecord for mapping):

```
[Property(ColumnType = "My.Common.Repository.UserTypes.DelimitedList, My.Common.Repository")]
public virtual IList<string> FooBar { get; set; }
```